# Calculate surface limited by curve

Tags: surfaces, parametric

How to calculate the surface limited by the curve described with the two equations:

$x = 3+cos(t)$

$y=4sin(t)$

The formula we use is the one shown below:

$\int_a^b |y(t).x'(t)| \,dt$

Now I'm wondering what I should use for $a$ and $b$. I also have no idea how to imagine a function like this so I don't know what surface is limited.

Thanks.

Comment: It may help: [plot](https://tinyurl.com/y2nze6wz) (a warning: the aspect ratio is *not* $1$). You probably know that $\cos(t),\sin(t)$ is a circle, what happens when it's translated and dilated on one coordinate? Note that sine and cosine are both $2\pi$-periodic. This should give a hint about the interval of integration.

Comment: So the interval of integration is always the period of the two functions? So that $a=0$ and $b=2π$?